# Adding cordova SalesforceMobileSDK Plugin is failing using forcehybrid

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

On A Mac, macOS Big Sur.

Hello, when I run forcehybrid create for either IOS or Android both are failing at the command

```
plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin#v9.1.0 --force
```

When creating for IOS I get a Pod error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

When creating for Android I get an error about ANDROID_HOME not set to the path of Android SDK but I have ANDROID_HOME pointing to the right folder.

[image]

Comment: Update: Got Forcehybrid Create for Android to work, had a weird permission issue with my mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the sudo config and then I referenced this for my pod errors after
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403551/pod-install-failed-on-macos-big-sur